# Character recognition on direct camera in android?

Tags: android, ocr

I just wanted to know that,

As bar-code scanner works in Android.
Is that possible to make ocr based application in android which will recognize the characters on the go only..

Means As I start my camera in application, it should start doing its work instead of taking a picture and then recognize...

Thank you  in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OpenCV for Android. For on the fly recognition you can see how BarCodeScanner implements it [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

[OpenCV4Android](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/OpenCV4Android)